# Apply shadowBlur only to only 1 element on HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

In my HTML canvas, I'm trying to apply the style `shadowBlur`, ONLY to the text element that says 'Artwork 1'.

But current if you see by running the code snippet, the shadowBlur gets applied to every other element too.

I also tried using `ctx.save()` and `ctx.restore()` too but it doesnt seem to work.

Any help is appreciated

```js
var container = 'body';
var size = {
 x: $(container).width(),
 y: $(container).height()
};

var canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({width: size.x, height: size.y}).appendTo(container),
    ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';


window.requestFrame = (function(){
 return  window.requestAnimationFrame 
})();


function render(){


 ctx.clearRect(0,0,size.x,size.y);

  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.shadowColor = '#fff';

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-20,size.y/2);
  for(var x = 0; x < size.x; x++){

   ctx.lineTo(x,size.y/2+0.6*(20),1,1);

   if (x == 100.00) {
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText("Artwork 1 ",x,(size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 25 ));
    ctx.shadowBlur = 50; /* this is applied to all elements instead of just the text*/
    ctx.save();

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x, (size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 10 ), 20, 20);
   }


   if (x == 300.00) {
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText("Artwork 2 ",x,(size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 25 ));


    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x, (size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 10 ), 20, 20);
   }

  }
  
  ctx.stroke();

 requestFrame(render);
} /* END fn render */

render();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}
html canvas, body canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the shadow *before* rendering the text, then turn it off afterward:

```
ctx.shadowBlur = 20;  // call before draw operation require shadow
ctx.fillText("Artwork 1 ",x,(size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 25 ));
ctx.shadowBlur = 0;   // remove shadow
```

Notice since the shadow in the previous code is overdrawn several times the result of new code will make it appear "weaker" which either force you to use a smaller blur radius (as shown) or to overdraw the text a couple of times (will require a different composition mode than xor).

The `save()` call can be removed.

```js
var container = 'body';
var size = {
 x: $(container).width(),
 y: $(container).height()
};

var canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({width: size.x, height: size.y}).appendTo(container),
    ctx = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';


window.requestFrame = (function(){
 return  window.requestAnimationFrame 
})();


function render(){


 ctx.clearRect(0,0,size.x,size.y);

  ctx.lineWidth = 10;
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.shadowColor = '#fff';

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(-20,size.y/2);
  for(var x = 0; x < size.x; x++){

   ctx.lineTo(x,size.y/2+0.6*(20),1,1);

   if (x == 100.00) {
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 20; /* this is applied to all elements instead of just the text*/
    ctx.fillText("Artwork 1 ",x,(size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 25 ));
    ctx.shadowBlur = 0;

    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x, (size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 10 ), 20, 20);
   }


   if (x == 300.00) {
    ctx.font = "20px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillText("Artwork 2 ",x,(size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 25 ));


    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
    ctx.fillRect(x, (size.y/2+0.6*(20)- 10 ), 20, 20);
   }

  }
  
  ctx.stroke();

 requestFrame(render);
} /* END fn render */

render();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}
html canvas, body canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @wsgg no problem! I forgot to mention that to fully turn off shadow you should also set `ctx.shadowColor = "transparent";`.